# Replacing the first character of a string with another string

Tags: php, replace

I'm trying to replace the first character of a string with words, but I'm running into some trouble here. I'm only able to replace the character with the first character of the string, and not the entire string. How would I fix this?

```
$type = "xgo xgo xgo";
$ifX = $type[0];

if ($ifX == "x") {
$type[0] = "do not ";
}
```

**Result:**

```
dgo xgo xgo
```

**Want Result:**

```
do not go xgo xgo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
$type = "xgo xgo xgo";
echo preg_replace('/x/', 'do not ', $type, 1); // output : do not go xgo xgo
```

If you dont specity 4th parameter, your output looks like this

```
do not go do not go do not go// all x are replaced.
```

Comment: what's the fourth parameter do?

Comment: Its the count. If i dont specify, it will replace `x` to `do not` in the whole string. Or we can tell that how many times we want to replace X in string.

Comment: Well that saves making another method called preg_replace_all ;)

Comment: Getting expected result??